# my crawl data not coming in json,csv its showing blank to me but in cmd its coming

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I typed to export data in json

`scrapy crawl mydata -o items.json`

but while i open items.json in notepad++ it's showing blank to me

Here's my spider

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re
class mymyweb(BaseSpider):
    name = "myweb"
    allowed_domains = ["myweb.in"]
    start_urls = ["myweb.in/?iPathId=84731"]

    def parse(self,response):
        hoteldata = response.selector.xpath("//*[@id='js_itemlist']")
        for hoteldata in hoteldata:
            title = hoteldata.xpath("//*[re:match(@id, '[0-9]+')]/span/text()").extract()
            print title
```

Comment: Please give more information, like what you expect and what you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Well, to give you a solution on your problem we need to see your `mydata` spider and the `item` you fill in with the spider. Without this there is no hope we can give you any advice.

Comment: i scraped data from particular website and i m getting data in console but now i want that data export in json format or called it in anyname.json  format. When i m trying to use command  scrapy crawl spider_name.py -o anyname.json its giving me blank document

Comment: from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re

class mymyweb(BaseSpider):
 name = "myweb"
 allowed_domains = ["myweb.in"]
 start_urls = ["http://www.myweb.in/?iPathId=84731"]
 
 def parse(self,response):
  hoteldata = response.selector.xpath("//*[@id='js_itemlist']")
  for hoteldata in hoteldata:
   title = hoteldata.xpath("//*[re:match(@id, '[0-9]+')]/span/text()").extract()
   print title

Comment: thanks @GHajba check out the spider

Comment: If this is the whole code do not wonder that you are getting an empty JSON file. You do not export any items...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have items exported (and to be able to get results when running `scrapy crawl mydata -o items.json`) you have to define items in your project as described in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#defining-our-item).

After the item is defined you have to make sure you fill the item with values and `return` or `yield` the item. For a reference how to do this look at the docs [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#using-our-item).

After this is done you will get elements in your JSON file.